# Connect from PHP to an Oracle DB using an Oracle Wallet

Tags: php, oracle

Is it possible to configure PHP to use a secure external password store as described in http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cnctslsh.htm?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, you need to:
1 - create a wallet (as explained in your link)
2 - put the Oracle instant client and the wallet files somewhere on the server with Apache+PHP (for example /opt/instantclient and /opt/wallet)
3 - start Apache with the following variables:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/instantclient   
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/instantclient   
TNS_ADMIN=/opt/wallet
```

4 - In /opt/wallet create a tnsnames.ora files with this content:

```
WALLET_NAME =  
  (DESCRIPTION =  
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DB_IP)(PORT = DB_PORT))    
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DB_SID))    
  )
```

where WALLET_NAME it's the name of the wallet chosen when the wallet has been created, DB_IP it's the database ip address or hostname, DB_PORT it's the db port, and DB_SID it's the sid of the database
5 - In /opt/wallet create a sqlnet.ora files with this content:

```
WALLET_LOCATION =    
   (SOURCE =     
     (METHOD = FILE)     
     (METHOD_DATA =     
       (DIRECTORY = /opt/wallet)     
     )      
    )     

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
```

6 - restart Apache

On the PHP code side now you can connect to the database opening a connection with the following code:

```
$conn = oci_connect("/", "", "WALLET_NAME", null, OCI_CRED_EXT);
```

you can use otherwise the oci_pconnect, for persistent connections, and the same syntax
I hope this helps and i didn't forget anything